# Arduino- Files created by computer don't exist

Tags: arduino

I am using the Ethernet Shield's SD card functionality. I can write new files to it, and it works fine, but any files I create on it on my computer return false with `SD.exists("test.html");` It is a 32GB FAT32 card. I also tried making the names of the files all caps, and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

In FAT, files can only have 3 letter file extensions, therefore needing a .htm extension. I feel stupid now :P